# Binding Spring Beans to Services in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails

How can I bind my list declared in Spring DSL to the parameter of my service?

I have the following beans declaration

```
beans = {
   defaultSkillList = [
       { Skill s  -> 
             name="Shooting"    
             description = "Shooting things..."},
   { Skill s ->
             name="Athletics"
             description = "Running, jumping, dodging ..."}
     ]
}
```

And I have the following service declaration:

```
class GameService {

    def defaultSkillList

    def createGame(Game gameInstance) {
       //...
    }
}
```

I currently get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to access the `defaultSkillList`.

How should I be accessing this bean?

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare a list like that in the beans DSL, you'd need something like

```
beans = {
  defaultSkillList(ArrayList, [....])
}
```

but the DSL won't let you define a list of anonymous inner beans (well, it will accept the syntax `defaultSkillList(ArrayList, [{Skill s -> ...},  ... ]` but it'll give you a list of closures rather than treating the closures as bean definitions).  You'll need to declare the individual beans with names and then `ref` them, e.g.

```
beans = {
  'skill-1'(Skill) {
    name="Shooting"    
    description = "Shooting things..."
  }
  'skill-2'(Skill) {
    name="Athletics"
    description = "Running, jumping, dodging ..."
  }

  defaultSkillList(ArrayList, [ref('skill-1'), ref('skill-2')])
}
```

or just give up on the DSL and use XML in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml` instead:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

  <util:list id="defaultSkillList">
    <bean class="com.example.Skill" p:name="Shooting" p:description="..." />
    <bean class="com.example.Skill" p:name="Athletics" p:description="..." />
  </util:list>
</beans>
```

Comment: Cool, No big deal for me to use the spring format.  The service is defined correctly right?